# Neo4j StatementResult too slow

Tags: java, performance, neo4j

I use java driver to connect Neo4j database. I wrote below code to query and get result.

```
StatementResult response = session.run("MATCH (a:File {id:'" + file + "'}) RETURN a.pagerank");
while(response.hasNext())
    sumPageRank += response.next().get("a.pagerank").asDouble();
```

But this runs too slow. After profiling, I see that the first statement runs fine but `hasNext()` method makes it slow contrary to my expectation. Because it looks like getting a response is fast but parsing that response is slow. Then, I tried list() method:

```
StatementResult response = session.run("MATCH (a:File {id:'" + file + "'}) RETURN a.pagerank");
List<Record> records = response.list();
for(Record r : records)                    
    sumPageRank += r.get("a.pagerank").asDouble();
```

That is slow, too. What it makes slow is `list()` method. So, I am looking for a fast way to get a response from `cypher` query.

Comment: Make sure you've created an index (or a unique constraint, since `id` should probably be unique for a :File) on :File(id) so the lookup is quick. You want to make sure when you PROFILE the query that you see a NodeByIndexSeek operation.

Comment: Please Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21138715/slow-results-retrieval-from-cypher-query-in-java-neo4j-2-0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're attempting to do a sum operation on the pagerank across all results. It's more efficient if you do this in query itself (and also use parameters here, passing `fileId` in the parameter map, rather than string appending the id):

```
MATCH (a:File {id:$fileId}) 
RETURN sum(a.pagerank) as sumPageRank
```

Comment: In database, each file has a `pageRank` field. This query returns the `pageRank` of a single file, doesn't it? How can I return the sum of `pageRank` of multiple files? Lets say, there are there files: X,Y,Z. What is the query that returns `X.pageRank+Y.pageRank+Z.pageRank?`

Comment: Found it, `MATCH (a:File) WHERE a.id IN ["X","Y","Z"]  RETURN SUM(a.pagerank)` works, thank you!